# Remove Applications if there are no Notifications connected to the Apps using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a 'Notifications' app that displays different apps within it that may have notifications associated with them.  If the apps don't have notifications then just the apps themselves will be displayed.  Upon the apps being loaded I want a check to be done to see if there are notifications associated with the apps.  If no notifications exist then I want the apps to not be displayed or removed.  I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

I believe I need to add some code in `listenForNotifications` or `getApps` to check and see if there are any and if there isn't then 'delete' the apps. `getApps` gets hit first and pulls in apps the user may have.  So maybe a check in there to see if any notifications are associated with the app?  I thought I was on the right track, but it still isn't working.

CONTROLLER

```
function NotificationsCtrl($scope, $state, Service, SecService, RecService) {
var vm = this;
vm.ctrlName = 'NotificationsCtrl';

$scope.showMenu = false;

$scope.appList = {};

$scope.dismissNotification = function(notification) {
  EcosystemService.dismissNotification(notification.id).then(
    function (response) {
      delete $scope.appList[notification.appId].notifications[notification.id];
    });
};

$scope.dismissNotifications = function(app) {
  var notifications = app.notifications;
  for (var id in notifications) {
    EcosystemService.dismissNotification(notifications[id].id).then(
      function(notificationId) {
        return function (response) {
          delete app.notifications[notificationId];
        }
      }(id));
  }
};

$scope.init = function () {
  Service.getUserAppsByEmail(SecService.secState.username).then(function (response) {
    var apps = response.applications;
    $scope.appList['notes'] = {
      name: 'Notes',
      notifications: {}
    } ;
    for(var i = 0; i < apps.length; i++) {
      $scope.appList[apps[i].appId] = {
        name: apps[i].name,
        icon: apps[i].icon,
        notifications: {}
      }
    }
  });  
};

function listenForNotifications() {
  RealtimeService.on("notifications", function (data) {
    var app = $scope.appList[data.body.appId];
    if (app != null) {
      if(!data.body.dismissed) {
        data.body.unixEpoch = Date.parse(data.body.whenCreated);
        app.notifications[data.body.id] = data.body;
      }
      else {
        delete app.notifications[data.body.id];
        delete app.appList[data.body.appId];
      }
    }
    else {
      delete app.appList[data.body.appId];
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally fixed the issue...
Adding this in the HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="app in appList" ng-show="(app.notifications | AssociativeArrayFilter) > 0">
```

And adding this in the Controller

```
angular.module('notifications').filter('AssociativeArrayFilter', function () {
return function (collection) {
  if (!collection) {
    return 0;
  }

  var reCount = 0;
  angular.forEach(collection, function (val, index) {
    reCount++;
  });

  return reCount;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="app in appList" ng-if="app.notifications.length > 0">
     .......
</div>
<div ng-if="noNotifications()">No notifications!</div>

$scope.noNotifications = function() {
    var foundNotifications = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.appList, function(app, index) {
        foundNotifications = foundNotifications && app.notifications && app.notifications.length > 0;
    });
    return !foundNotifications;
};
```

EDIT: I added a simpler solution for showing the "No notifications" by checking the `$scope.noNotifications()` function.

Comment: That was a simple fix.  Thanks!

Comment: I would also like to display a message if there are no apps available.  Could I include that in the HTML as well?

Comment: @jedinerd - I added something that SHOULD work, because I can't test it locally right now

Comment: This does remove the apps, but when 'Alerts' has notifications it still isn't displayed. In `listenForNotifications()` , `if(!data.body.dismissed)` is equal to false.  So it prevents the app from showing even if it has notifications.  So I believe more needs to be done.  I feel like that answer is headed in the right direction though.

Comment: Still isn't functioning properly.  No apps are being displayed.  I inserted notifications into the alert app so it should be displayed, but still no app is showing.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is on the view side or the controller. try to add `{{ appList | json }}` before the `ngRepeat` part and see the current object state. If the state is as you expected then the problem is with the view, otherwise, you need to check the code in your controller

Comment: When debugging `listenForNotifications()` and `if(!data.body.dismissed)` are never hit in the controller now that I have added that code.  I am not sure why though.

Comment: I reverted back the the original solution and i'm checking if there are notifications using a function instead of filtering the list. I hope it helps

Comment: This does help, but still isn't working correctly.  The message shows up briefly and then goes away.  And the alerts app still isn't showing up and it has notifications.  I will try to figure out what the issue is.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still haven't solved this issue.  I added some more code to see if that helps to understand the problem better.

Comment: The `<ng-if="app.notifications.length > 0>"` is what is causing no apps to be shown at all.  Something isn't right here.